# NativeCall can't find a function in Kernel32.dll

Tags: windows, winapi, raku, nativecall

I am trying to port [this code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/reading-input-buffer-events) to Perl6. While I can call `GetStdHandle`, `GetConsoleMode` and `SetConsoleMode`, my script breaks when I try to call `ReadConsoleInput`:

```
Cannot locate symbol 'ReadConsoleInput' in native library 'Kernel32.dll'
  in method setup at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\sources\947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 287
  in method CALL-ME at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\sources\947BDAB9F96E0E5FCCB383124F923A6BF6F8D76B (NativeCall) line 576
  in block <unit> at test.p6 line 149
```

Now, that function is [definitly there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput). It has a a complex signature though, which I am not sure I got right in my script. Could that be the reason? Does NativeCall look at the signature?

This is how I defined the sub in my code (the comment is taken from the MS docs)

```
#BOOL WINAPI ReadConsoleInput( _In_ HANDLE hConsoleInput, _Out_ PINPUT_RECORD lpBuffer, _In_ DWORD nLength, _Out_ LPDWORD lpNumberOfEventsRead );
sub ReadConsoleInput(Pointer[void], INPUT_RECORD is rw, uint32, uint32 is rw) is native('Kernel32') returns Bool { * };
```

I can post the rest my code if needed, but it is A LOT of boilerplate because of all the structs and stuff I have to define and which usually come from header files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real function name is `ReadConsoleInputA` or `ReadConsoleInputW`, depending on whether you want ANSI or Unicode (UTF-16) input. The C headers have macros that automatically translate `ReadConsoleInput` to the correct function based on preprocessor symbols. But when you are loading functions at run-time like this, you have to specify exactly which function you want.

Comment: Aaaand it works. One step closer to Term::win32io. Thanks a lot.